# SVG <image> tag inlined in HTML not loading image in browser

Tags: html, cross-browser, svg

Trying to load an image in SVG using an HTML page:

```
<html>
...
<svg>
<image x="330" y="137" width="320" height="38" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="/img/title.png"></image>
</svg>
...
</html>
```

All other elements in the svg load up (paths shapes text) except image. Any way to get this working in browsers? I've tried Chrome, Firefox, IE. All browsers are missing the image.

Using Chrome I found that Chrome doesn't even send the request for the image. I have a hunch it's the same for IE and Firefox.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use:

```
<image ... xlink:href="...">
```

See [the SVG Document Structure spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElementHrefAttribute).

Comment: And along with this, you need your document to be served as XHTML and have the proper `xlink` namespace declared on the SVG element: `<svg ... xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`.

Comment: Additionally, if you are creating the image dynamically you need to do the following:
`svgImage.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'title.png');`

Comment: @NeilFraser Thank you so much!!!! Your comment about using "setAttributeNS" instead of just "setAttribute" on the image was so important and it helped me solve this problem after HOURS and HOURS of banging my head as to why the image wasn't showing up. Thank a ton.

Comment: can you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263136/svg-image-not-loading-in-firefox) please

Answer (score 2):

This is not the case in question, but I ran across a similar issue with an `<image href="/path/to/file.svg">` tag not showing up in Edge, while working correctly in Firefox and Chrome.

It turns out that if you don't explicitly set both a `height` and a `width` attribute on the `<image>` tag Edge won't show the image. This is not the case in Chrome and Firefox where `width` alone was enough.