# SVG Image Not Loading in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg, xlink

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/maNbWQ) and at the bottom of this question is the actual code. Although the code works fine in Chrome, for some reason `image` elements in an `svg` element are not loading in Firefox. I've tested it on Firefox versions `64` and `64.0.2`. Neither loads the images.

Based on an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6643284/7543162) I came across, and the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#XLinkRefAttrs) itself, I've tried a number of different things, none of which worked. Some of the things I've tried are...

1. `<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ... >`
2. `<image xlink:href='...' href='...'`

**Is this a bug with Firefox's implementation of SVG?** I've discovered bugs with Firefox's SVG implementation before, so I wouldn't be surprised.

## HTML

```
<svg id='svg' viewBox='0 0 6144 4608' version='1.1'>
  <image x='0' y='0' preserveAspectRatio='none'
    xlink:href='https://i.postimg.cc/hvH4yn2Q/map.jpg'
    id='background-image' />
  <clipPath id='eye'>
    <rect id='rectangle' x='3172' y='2404' rx='10' ry='10' />
  </clipPath>
  <image x='0' y='0' preserveAspectRatio='none'
    xlink:href='https://i.postimg.cc/hvH4yn2Q/map.jpg'
    id='main-image'/>
</svg>
```

## CSS

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#svg {
  width: 6144px;
  height: 4608px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3072px; /* set with JS */
  top: -2304px; /* set with JS */
}

#background-image {
  width: 6144px;
  height: 4608px;
  opacity: 0.25;
}

rect {
  width: 35vw;
  height: 75vh;
}

#main-image {
  width: 6144px;
  height: 4608px;
  clip-path: url(#eye);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG <image> tag not working in Safari and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390962/svg-image-tag-not-working-in-safari-and-firefox)

Comment: @Kaiido it's not a duplicate. the issue has nothing to do with missing `width` and `height` properties, which are set in css...

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate, the `width` and `height` **attributes** must be set for Firefox to load this image, just like the SVG1.1 specs required. Setting it through CSS was not enough. In svg2 this will change, but FF still doesn't support this part of SVG2 (while Chrome does).

Comment: Oh and actually I missed it, but even your `<rect>` needs its **attributes** in svg1.1, but your `vw` and `vh` units won't work there: https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/gZVOQL

Comment: @Kaiido so if i add random values for the `width` and `height` attributes in the HTML, i can still modify them on page load via JS and HTML/SVG1.1 will respect that right?

Comment: Yes, with js you can, but setting the sizes through CSS was not supported in SVG1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` and `height` attributes [*must*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image#Specific_attributes) be assigned to the `image` element in the actual HTML for SVG version 1.1:

```html
<svg id='svg' viewBox='0 0 6144 4608' version='1.1'>
  <image x='0' y='0' width="100%"; height="100%" 
    xlink:href='https://i.postimg.cc/hvH4yn2Q/map.jpg'
    />
</svg>
```

Comment: **Were** required and it's `width` not `whidth`

Comment: @Anthony "**attributes**", the little things you put in the tags inside the XML markup. And "*were*" because [SVG2 specs](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/geometry.html#Sizing) now support an `auto` value. So *were* is correct now that some UAs have implemented it. That community driven MDN didn't catch on is just inconsistency when we see they already deprecated `xlink:href`somewhere else, but it will flatten sometime eventually.

Comment: @Kaiido ahh didnt know the specs changed

Answer (score 0):

Check the image mime type, it must be: image/svg+xml